# Stack snippet console affected by div style

Tags: bug, design, stack-snippets

If we add CSS on `div` inside the stack snippet, the console will be affected by the style as shown the snippet below (when we increase the padding the console also will be affected):

```js
console.log('Foo');
console.log('Bar');
```

```css
div{
   padding:50px;
   background-color: green;
   color: white;
}
```